# How to make a Windows 10 computer go to sleep with a python script?

Tags: python, windows-10, sleep

How can I make a computer sleep with a python script?

It has to be *sleep*, not hibernate or anything else.

I have tried to use `cmd` but there is no command to sleep or I didn't find one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```
import os
os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
```

If this command doesn't work for you (it actually puts your comp. in hibernation mode) you will need to turn hibernation off:

```
Powercfg -H OFF
```

To turn hibernation mode back on:

```
Powercfg -H ON
```

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep
```

If you *don't* want to turn hibernation off just to run a command, you can use [psshutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) as an alternative

```
C:\Windows\System32\psshutdown.exe -d -t 0
```

As for what `os.system` does, straight from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.

An additional note:

You will need to have administrator permissions to run Powercfg -H *

Comment: to use psshutdown you have to download it from Ms website ( I thought it was a default tool)

Comment: Note: If you have sleep button on the keyboard you might think that your hibernation mode is already off since the computer sleeps (instead of hibernating) when clicking it. But I've discovered that this is not the case. If the command is making your computer hibernate you must use Powercfg -H OFF

Answer (score 2):

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

should work. Note 0,1,0 - that set is for sleep. Without - hibernation.

Comment: If hybernation is active, `0,1,0` will go to hybernation anyway

Answer (score 0):

set hdd close wait time = 0 in power options