# How to turn windows 10 laptop to sleep with google colab?

Tags: windows-10, command, google-colaboratory, sleep

I tried to make my computer to sleep after finished running a time-consuming computation in google colab.

I have turn off the windows automatic sleep function to ensure my code running uninterrupted.

I have found a code for python from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009777/how-to-make-a-windows-10-computer-go-to-sleep-with-a-python-script), but it doesn't work in google colab, such as.

```
import os
os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
os.system( )
```

This code will only return a number of `32512`

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab runs on a cloud virtual machine and not on your local computer. When you import os you are importing it on the virtual machine. This code will try to make that os sleep and will fail to do so because of lack of permission.