# Sleep and wake computer with python?

Tags: python, hibernate, sleep, suspend, wake

I'd like to write a little python script that puts my computer to sleep/sleep/sleep, and it would be possible to wake it up after X minutes.

Which function does the trick?

Edit: Im using windows 10 home

Edit2: OK thanks!
I managed to get him to sleep.
But still don't understand how to wake him up after x minutes.?
Thank you again

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Comment: if you have a windows 10 computer you can use call the cmd using os.system() to sleep, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009777/how-to-make-a-windows-10-computer-go-to-sleep-with-a-python-script

Comment: Not sure if this works, but to awaken try using pyautogui and move your mouse: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-keep-your-pc-awake-automatically-using-python/

Comment: You'll want to use `os.system` to issue a command in a subshell: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system The correct command will depend on your operating system, it's exactly the same commands as you can use on the command line.